# Creating and Using a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 class UniversityAthletics():
    def _init_(self, university_name, sport):
        self.university_name = university_name
        self.sport = sport

    def describe_athletics(self):
        print(self.university_name.title() + " " + self.sport.title())

    def in_season(self):
        print(self.sport.title() + " is in season.")


athletics = UniversityAthletics('salisbury university', 'soccer')

print("The school name is " + athletics.university_name.title() + ".")
print(str(athletics.sport.title()) + " is in season")

athletics.describe_athletics()
athletics.in_season()
```

Guys, I'm just learning how to code so if I say something that makes no sense my apologies. 
But I'm trying to give the class UniversityAthletics the attributes

> 'salisbury university', 'soccer'

but when I try to execute the program I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:/WorWic/IntroToProgramming/chapter9/University Athletics.py", line 13, in 
>       athletics = UniversityAthletics('salisbury university', 'soccer') TypeError: object() takes no parameters

I've gone back to the book that my professor gave me and still cannot find a solution. There must be something simple and plain that I missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `init` method is named `_init_` (one underscore on each side), when it should be `__init__` (two underscores on each side).

Because the method is named wrong, python is not finding it, and instead directly calling the method in the superclass of your class, which is:

`object.__init__`

and passing it your two parameters, which it is not expecting.. hence the error message.

Answer (score 2):

The `__init__` function needs double underscores on either sides (you have only singles).

Comment: wow... -_-  the dang textbook didn't even mention that. But thanks, dude. Told you "something simple"

Answer (score 2):

It's 2 lines around the `init`, so instead of `_init_` type `__init__`.